# Is there a way to view the total number of comments I've ever made?

Tags: feature-request, comments

This request is different from being able to exactly see one's own deleted comments. I'm simply asking for the count of total comments that I've made (deleted and undeleted both).

**Reason:** comments - when they become obsolete - get flagged and deleted. When  my profile page says 500 comments, there may actually have been 1000 comments instead, where the remaining five hundred got deleted. I'm interested in seeing the full picture of my participation on a SE site.

Comment: Do you intend to include comments on deleted posts? For <10k rep users (and maybe the others), the Activity>All actions> Comments list doesn't show my comments on posts which got deleted later, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Chair Good point. I would be including comments on deleted posts, because I want the total number of comments I've ever made, irrespective of whether I'm >10k or <10k.